# Display Object In Crystal Report If One Or More Records Contains Specific Data

Tags: crystal-reports, global-variables, formula

I have a Crystal Report (*CR Developer v11.5.12.1838*) in which I only want to display certain totals in the **Report Footer** if one or more of the detail records contains a specific piece of information. To this end, I've created three formulas in the report:

- `InitDisplayLIATotals` - Placed (and suppressed) in the **Report Header** section

```cpp
Global BooleanVar LIA := False;
```

- `SetDisplayLIATotals` - Placed in a (suppressed) **Group Header** (the only group header in the report) *NOTE: I've also tried placing it in the **Detail** section*

```cpp
Global BooleanVar LIA;

WhilePrintingRecords;

If LIA = False Then
    If Not IsNull({mydata.liamp}) And Not (Trim({mydata.liamp}) = "") Then
        LIA := True;
```

- `DisplayLIATotals` - Placed in the **Report Footer** and used in the suppression formula for the totals "label" object.

```cpp
Global BooleanVar LIA;

LIA;
```

The intention is that the formulae should *ONLY* return `True` if one or more records in the current data set has a non-NULL value in the `mydata.liamp` field (regardless of record position). If all the records in the data set have a NULL value in this field, it should return `False`.

However, I can't seem to get it working correctly.  I put the formula as a printable field in the **Report Footer** to confirm, and it always prints `False`, even when I know it should return `True`. When I place the formula in the **Detail** section (and make it visible), I see it return `True` on the first record, but all subsequent records show it as `False`, resulting in a `False` value in the **Report Footer**.

I've not mastered the art of writing formulae in Crystal Reports so I'm sure I'm just missing/overlooking something here, but I'm not sure what that would be. Could someone help me figure out why I can't reliably get it to return the correct value?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the WhilePrintingRecords?

Comment: @heringer - My first attempt didn't include the `WhilePrintingRecords;` directive, but resulted in a `False` value returned in the **Report Footer** section. I added that in the hopes that it would evaluate the values correctly. Your comment, however, did get me thinking about it. Perhaps I need to add that directive to *all* of the formulae for it to work correctly.

Comment: @heringer - It appears that including the `WhilePrintingRecords;` directive in *all three* of the formulas was the key, although it was still a bit "odd" when I previewed the report. I still had the `SetDisplayLIATotals` visible in the **Group Header** and, while it appropriately showed the first record to "switch" the value as `True`, all other records still showed `False`. Still, the `DisplayLIATotals` value in the **Report Footer** correctly reported as `True`, so I'm guessing it's simply because the "set" formula isn't *actually* returning the current value.

Comment: @heringer - Regardless, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you'd like to post your suggestion (or, it's inverse anyway) as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpfull. I will not post as an answer, since it is not really the answer :) But i encourage you to post your own solution to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion from @heringer in the question's comments, I was able to find the solution through some trial and error. The key is apparently in the `WhilePrintingRecords;` directive used by the Crystal Reports Formula Editor. For the report to properly evaluate the condition all the way throughout the report so that it returns the "correct" value for the **Report Footer** section, *all three* of the formulas require this directive set.

I found this explanation in the [SAP Community forums](https://answers.sap.com/answers/10805129/view.html):

> ### WhileReadingRecords
>
> Forces the program to evaluate the formula while it is reading database record data.
>
> *If you try to include a group in this formula, you will get an error message.*
>
> ### WhilePrintingRecords
>
> Forces the program to evaluate the formula while it is printing database record data.

Not terribly descriptive there, but my understanding of it is that the `WhilePrintingRecords;` directive causes the formula to wait to evaluate each data element until the report is *actually* being generated (printer, display, export, etc.), so all of the data has been loaded into each of the fields of the report.

*I don't think it would go amiss if someone who is more familiar with Crystal Reports could provide a better or more detailed explanation of these directives and the "multi-pass engine".*

---

**EDIT -** I found a question that might help to better explain the use of these directives:

**[why use beforereadingrecords / whilereadingrecords / whileprintingrecords in crystal reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990431/why-use-beforereadingrecords-whilereadingrecords-whileprintingrecords-in-cry)**

---

The end result is the following:

- `InitDisplayLIATotals` - Placed (suppressed) in the **Report Header** section

```cpp
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar LIA := False;
```

- `SetDisplayLIATotals` - Placed (suppressed) in a **Group Header** (*or **Detail** section*)

```cpp
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar LIA;

If LIA = False Then
    If Not IsNull({mydata.liamp}) And Not (Trim({mydata.liamp}) = "") Then
        LIA := True;
```

- `DisplayLIATotals` - Placed in the **Report Footer** and/or used in a suppression formula.

```cpp
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar LIA;

LIA;
```

I hope this is helpful to anyone else who might be struggling with getting this technique to work.

---

### SIDE NOTE

I actually *was* able to "work around" the problem to a certain extent by making use of a **Running Total Field**. I created a **COUNT** summary of the `mydata.liamp` field, which apparently only counts non-NULL values. Using this summary field in the suppression formula *DID* work because of the data in my testing data set, but it's an imperfect solution.

The "problem" is that the field *may* contain empty string values which (*I assume*) would be included in the count. For my use case scenario, I wanted to be certain only values that were non-NULL *and* not empty count towards switching this value. The "[three-formula trick](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/quick-tip-crystal-reports-three-formula-trick/)" (*a TechRepublic "QuickTip" article for reference*) allows me to test for both possibilities.